# How to return an pointer to an item in the linear list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

i have funcion that search a key in the linear list, but i have error when i want return pointer on an element.

```
struct Item
{
    datatype key;
    Item* next;
   Item* prev;
};

int List::search(int x)
{
    Item* temp = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty List" << endl;
    }
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->key == x) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return *temp;\\here i have a error
}
```

Comment: where `head` is defined? `if (head == NULL)` that way *temp will dereference from NULL pointer

Comment: You should always post the error with your question, but I'm guessing it's that the type doesn't match the function signature.  It should be like `Item List::search(int x)`

Comment: @Михайло Куриця The function return type is int. Do you see this? When why are you asking your question?!

Comment: @shjeff in the class List, i forgor add it

Comment: if you want to return pointer to an Item then you should change `int List::search(int x)` to `Item* List::search(int x)`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i say that i have error,  meaning that i want to fix it:)

Comment: @МихайлоКуриця Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to return the whole node. In this case the user can break your list using the function. The implementation of the list should be hidden.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm just a student and did everything according to the algorithm given to us and it says that I have to return the pointer to the found element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to return an pointer to an item in the linear list

It is evident that for starters you need to change the return type of the function from `int` to `Item *`.

```
Item * List::search( int x );
```

And within function you need to return indeed a pointer instead of the pointed item.

The function should not output any message. It is the user of the function that will decide to output any message or not dependent on whether a null pointer is returned or not.

The function should be overloaded for constant and non-constant list.

Here is shown how it can be defined

```
Item * List::search( int x )
{
    Item *target = head;

    while ( target != nullptr && target->key != x )
    {
        target = target->next;
    }

    return target;
}
```

and

```
const Item * List::search( int x ) const
{
    const Item *target = head;

    while ( target != nullptr && target->key != x )
    {
        target = target->next;
    }

    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
int List::search(int x)
{
  Item* temp = head;
  ...
  return *temp;\\here i have a error
}
```

If you want to obtain a pointer to an element, then the function should return `Item*`, not `int`.

If `temp` is an `Item*`, then `*temp` is an `Item`. It is neither an `Item*` nor an `int`.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try to change:

```
Item* List::search(int x)
{
    Item* temp = head;
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty List" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->key == x) 
        {
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```